# PHP script not submitting HTML form data to the database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I really need help at this moment.
I am trying to make an application that records cash/bank payments.

I have a table called 'cashbook'. It stores data about cash/bank payments. It has 8 columns:

```
id (stores transaction id)
enter code here
tdate (stores transaction date
chequeno (stores cheque number, if the payment is made by cheque)
originator (stores the name of the person to whom payment is made)
cr_amount (stores the amount of cash/bank payment)
tclass (stores the information about the class of transaction)
pmode (stores the mode of transaction-cash or bank)
payer (stores the name of the person making the payment)
```

I am making a program that will insert data into specific columns of the 'cashbook' table when certain conditions are met. I have defined 4
conditions on which to record cash/bank payments.

Below is the html form that is used to collect data:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#designation').on('change', function(){
        if ( this.value == '1')
        {
            $("#supp").show();
            $("#paye").hide();
        }
        else if ( this.value == '2')
        {
            $("#paye").show();
            $("#supp").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#supp").hide();
        }
    });
});
    

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pmoder').on('change', function(){
        if ( this.value == '2')
        {
            $("#chequeno").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#chequeno").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="post" action="registercash.php">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Date</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="tdate" type="date">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Mode of Payment</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="pmoder" name="pmode">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="chequeno" style="display: none;">
   <label>Cheque no</label>
   <input class="form-control" name="chequeno" >
   </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" >
   <label>Amount</label>
   <input class="form-control" name="tamount" >
   </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Designation / Supplier</label>
   <select class="form-control" id='designation' name="desig">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="paye" style="display: none;">
   <label>Name of Payee</label>
   <input class="form-control" name="payeename" >
   </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id='supp' style="display: none;">
   <label>Select Supplier</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="suppliername">
    <option>Ministry of Trade and Industry</option>
    <option>Okaikwei North Municipal Assembly</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Class</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="tclass">
    <option>Personnel Emoluments</option>
    <option>Materials & Office consumables</option>
    <option>Serminars & Conferences</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-default">Record</button>
 </form>
```

Below is the script that adds data to the 'cashbook' table:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Data</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    //including the database connection file
    include_once("config.php");

    $keyb = "";
    $keya = "";
    $chequeno = "";
    $keyc = "";
    $payeename = "";
    $suppliername = "";
    $tdate = "";
    $tclass = "";
    $tamount = "";
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
        $keyb = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['pmode']);
        $chequeno = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['chequeno']);
        $keyc = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['desig']);
        $payeename = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['payeename']);
        $suppliername = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['suppliername']);
        $tdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['tdate']);
        $tclass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['tclass']);
        $tamount = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['tamount']);
    }

    if(empty($keyb) || empty($keyc)|| empty($chequeno)|| empty($payeename)|| empty($suppliername)|| empty($tdate)|| empty($tclass)|| empty($tamount)) {
        if(empty($keyb)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Payment mode is empty.</font<br/>";
        }

        if(empty($keyc)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Designation is empty.</font><br/>";
        }
        if(empty($tdate)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Transaction date is empty.</font><br/>";
        }
        if(empty($tclass)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Transaction class is empty.</font><br/>";
        }
        if(empty($tamount)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Transaction amount is empty.</font><br/>";
        }
    } elseif ($keyb=="1" && $keyc =="2"){
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO cashbook(tdate, originator,     cr_amount, tclass, pmode, payer) VALUES   ('$tdate', '$payeename','$tamount', '$tclass','$keyb','$payeename')");
            echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
        echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";

    }elseif ($keyb=="2" && $keyc =="1"){
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO cashbook(tdate, chequeno, originator, cr_amount, tclass, pmode, payer) VALUES('$tdate', '$chequeno','$suppliername','$tamount','$tclass','$keyb','$payeename')");
        echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
        echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";

    }elseif ($keyb=="2" && $keyc =="2") {
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO cashbook(tdate, chequeno, originator, cr_amount, tclass, pmode, payer) VALUES('$tdate','$chequeno', '$payeename','$tamount', '$tclass','$keyb','$payeename')");
        echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
        echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
            
    }elseif ($keyb=="1" && $keyc =="1") {
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO cashbook(tdate, originator, cr_amount, tclass, pmode, payer) VALUES('$tdate','$suppliername','$tamount','$tclass','$keyb','$payeename')");
        echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
        echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
    }else {
        echo "error,,";
    }
    ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

My problem is that, the only time data gets inserted is when $keyb=='2' and $keyc=='2'(this is one of the conditions).
However, for the other 3 conditions, nothing gets inserted even in instances when those conditions are met.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Please format your code and use proper indentation.

Comment: Your <option> tags should have value attribute

Comment: What have you done so far to debug your code? Did you check the values of `$keyb` and  `$keyc`?

Comment: Yes, I did that. $keyb and $keyc output the expected values. but the script does not process it as expected

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a solution, but more a way of finding out exactly what is going wrong:

**Make sure you're getting the right values**

Send different keyb (`pmode`) and keyc (`desig`) values to the PHP script, and then do a `var_dump($_REQUEST);exit;` at the very top of the script to see what you're getting. Are you getting the values you're expecting?

**Make sure the SQL query is valid**

For each SQL query (`mysql_query()` call), make sure you catch any errors. Instead of just calling it like you're doing:

```
elseif ($keyb=="1" && $keyc =="2"){
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO ...");
    echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
    echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
}
```

Add an `if()` to catch any errors:

```
elseif ($keyb=="1" && $keyc =="2"){
    if(!$result = mysql_query($mysql, "INSERT..."){
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
    echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
}
```

**Simplify**

Finally, and this is more a stylistic note, I'd probably re-do your structure to not have so many `elseif()` sections. Maybe have it so that you format the query *string* based on the values and then just fire off the SQL query *once* in your code.

Comment: dearsina please I didn't get the last sentence of your last point titled 'Simplify'

Comment: @Clinton, OP has 4 `elseif()` sections where he keeps repeating a SQL query call and two lines of echos, that are all the same. A general rule of programming is that you should never write the same thing twice. Write it once, reference it many times. What OP can do is structure his code so that the `elseif()`s only pertain to the actual query itself, and then run the query and output the echo statements _once_.

Comment: I have applied your first point of making sure I'm getting the right values, and it output the expected values. Can you apply your second point in an example to set a path for me?

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example more in line with your code. Does that help?

Comment: Yes. thanks @dearsina. I actually solved the problem by breaking the if statements that checked for empty field with an else statement and then began a fresh if statement to execute my sql queries

Answer (score -1):

Firstly check your Query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT...");
```

Use `if()` to catch an errors:

also use this code to receive errors

```
if(!$result = mysql_query($mysql, "INSERT..."){

    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you've changed and why you think that this solves the problem?

Comment: I don't mean to be petty, but did you just copy-paste my answer?